# What is the 'd' in the literal 12d called?

Tags: c#, terminology, numbers, literals

I feel like I should know the answer to this, but I don't.

What is the type character on a numeric literal called?

```
double myDouble = 12d;
float myFloat = 10f;
```

I wanted to find a complete list of them today, but couldn't come up with what to ask Google to search for.

### EDIT

Found a decent list if anyone is interested

http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/08/secrets-and-lies-of-type-suffixes-in-c-and-vb-net/

Comment: Since there were 3 answers all at pretty much the same time, all slightly different I suppose it might not be defined terribly well :)

Comment: Note that it is a very bad idea to use lower case el as a type suffix. Suppose you have M(int) and M(long). Which one does M(5432l) call? Which one does M(54321) call? :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know if there is an official term but the C# language spec commonly refers to them as type suffixes.

Comment: Found exactly what I was looking for with 'c# type-suffix'.  Thanks to everyone who responded.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that the C# spec refers to them a such *make* it an official term?

Comment: @Joren essentially yes. What I meant by that statement is that there is not a line I know of which explicitly states "these are called type-suffix's".  It's just the common suffix used in the grammar

Answer (score 16):

It's called a data type suffix.

Answer (score 12):

Numeric Literal Suffix

A list:

- `uint:    u`
- `long:    l`
- `ulong:   ul`
- `float:   f`
- `decimal: m`

Answer (score 9):

The C# 3.0 specification ([MSWord file](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.doc)) refers to them as `type-suffix`, divided into two categories: `integer-type-suffix` and `real-type-suffix`.

`integer-type-suffix`es include:
U u  - unsigned int
L l - long
UL Ul uL ul LU Lu lU lu - unsigned long

`real-type-suffix`es include:
F f - float
D d - double
M m - decimal